# How to dispatch chained job after response

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I know it's possible to dispatch job after the response by using `dispatchAfterResponse`, however is it possible to dispatch a chained job after the response?

This is what I have so far.

```
JobNumberOne::withChain([
        new JobNumberTwo($data),
        new JobNumberThree($data),
])->dispatch($data);
```

What I want is to dispatch the job after the response.

Will it be possible?